# can I save a view of multiple worksheets in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

The image below is a view of two (2) worksheets in the same excel 2013 workbook. I made it using View--> View Side by Side, and the sizing each sheet, etc.

Is is possible to save this view so that when I re-open the file it is as I left it? How?

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible, but you can use some of the buttons on the 'View' ribbon bar to open the same sheet in a new Window and then arrange the windows as you like them with a different sheets active in each window.